# Converting a ggplot/manipulate plot to a plotly or a js-scripted plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-plotly

I'm trying to convert my ggplot to a plotly plot using ggplotly(). However, it doesn't seem to work on this code, after manipulate is acted on the plot. Is there any other way to do it?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(manipulate)
grades <- data.frame(Final = 20 * runif(70))
myFinalsPlot <- function(sliderInput, initialIndex, finalIndex) {
  ggplot(data.frame(grades$Final[initialIndex:finalIndex]),
     aes(x = grades$Final[initialIndex:finalIndex])) +
geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..),
               binwidth = sliderInput, colour = "green", fill = "yellow") +
geom_density(alpha = 0.2, fill = "#FF6666") +
labs(x = "Marks", y = "Grades")
}

myFinalsPlot <- manipulate(myFinalsPlot(slidersInput, 1, 70),
                       slidersInput = slider(1, 12, step = 1, initial = 5))
```

Comment: This looks to be an Rmarkdown doc with Shiny, right? For us to be able to help you, could you include more info (maybe a simplified version of your Rmarkdown doc with a sample data) ? Also, if you call ggplotly() on your doc in the console (no Shiny involved), does it work?

Comment: Noted. Could you indicate where the `manipulate()` function lies, i.e. which package?

Comment: No actually, this a standalone R file. I've just generated random data via rnorm, computed totals and allocated grades. I wanted to visualize it online, using a js tool.
Directly calling ggplotly() doesn't work; it gives the following error:
    Error in UseMethod("ggplotly", p) : 
      no applicable method for 'ggplotly' applied to an object of class "NULL"
NULL is what is returned by manipulated, when checked by class(myFinalsPlot)
I seem lost here.

Comment: manipulate() is in manipulate package

Comment: Posted an answer. I don't think it is supposed to work with plotly plots. For ggplot though, it worked for me after fixing an issue in your code :)

Comment: I added the packages to your code sample and also included a sample data (using runif).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, to make your code work with the `ggplot2` plot, there is an issue in your code that you need to fix. You shouldn't give the same name to your function and plot object. Replace this:

```
myFinalsPlot <- manipulate(myFinalsPlot(slidersInput, 1, 70),
                   slidersInput = slider(1, 12, step = 1, initial = 5))
```

By, e.g.:

```
myPlot <- manipulate(myFinalsPlot(slidersInput, 1, 70),
                   slidersInput = slider(1, 12, step = 1, initial = 5))
```

Now, regarding `plotly` plots, I don't think it is supposed to work with manipulate. I quote RStudio's website https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200551906-Interactive-Plotting-with-Manipulate:

> RStudio works with the manipulate package to add interactive capabilities to **standard** R plots.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. I've corrected my code as such.
Just on an aside, can you guide if I want to show count for histogram on primary y axis and density values on secondary y axis.

Comment: There are countless discussions are the topic of having a secondary axis in ggplot, see for example this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3101876/2699660 and the other comments/answers in the thread.